# Finding the max Y value in histogram image given I know the position X of the max value

Tags: numpy, scipy

I found the position of the maximum values from two halves in the histogram of an image using the argmax() function, But how can I find what is the max Y value at those points. Here is the code snippet I used to find the X-position of max-Y

```
histogram = np.sum(binary_warped[binary_warped.shape[0]/2:,:], axis=0)
half_width = np.int(histogram.shape[0]/2)
leftx = np.argmax(histogram[:half_width])
rightx = np.argmax(histogram[half_width:]) + half_width
```

[image: The image I am working with]

Comment: `argmax()` gives you the `x` (or the index in this case), and `max()` gives you the `y`. If you want the value at that `x`, simply index your histogram with the `argmax()` value. In other words, if you have an array `a`, then `a[argmax(a)]` is equal to `max(a)`.

Comment: Thanks!! fixed it